# returning a pointer as a function parameter

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a struct, for example:

```
typedef struct{
    int num;
} S, *Sp;
```

now, what I want to do is create a pointer of this type (without allocating memory), pass is to a function as a parameter and inside the function allocate the memory etc.
something like

```
void foo(Sp p){
    p = malloc.....
    p->num = ....
}
```

and then in main do something like this:

```
Sp new = NULL;
foo(new);
```

but after foo is done 'new' remains NULL, like it was never allocated. I feel like I'm doing something wrong here. 
(this is a small part of a HW assignment, and I can't change the function definition.)

Comment: C has value semantics.

Comment: C is passed-by-value language. you want to pass a reference, adding a level of pointer can solve your problem.

Comment: You can't change the function definition? How the hell does your instructor expect this to be possible?

Comment: you'll be surprised how many problems this assignment has. my instructor is not the best in writing it the right way or listening when someone tells him there's a problem

Comment: You cannot change the definition? Or just not the declaration?

Comment: `TE te_new; r = TQ_get_test(tq1, TQ_BEGIN, &te_new);` this is how it supposed to be used (it's part of an example we got and it has to work with it). `TE` is a struct (not a pointer)

Comment: That's entirely different. Then you are given `S new; foo(&new);` and want `void foo(Sp p) { p->num = ...; }`.

Comment: the thing is I have to allocate new memory in foo, since in the actual question num is a pointer. it'sa bit hard to explain here

Comment: Then allocate memory for `num`, not for `p`: `void foo(S *p) { p->num = malloc(...); }`.

Comment: ok. TE contains 2 pointers which are defined as `void*`. they're supposed to be generic, and I don't have the functions to allocate/copy seperate fields, only the whole TE, but the TE copy function allocates memory for the entire TE (basically makes a copy of the input).

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that in C, arguments are passed [by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) (not by reference). So when a function changes a formal argument, no change happens in the caller function. Hence, pass the address of your pointer.

```
void foo(S**pp) {
 *pp = malloc(sizeof(S));
 if (!*pp) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 // fill *pp
}
```

and call

```
S* ptr;
foo (&ptr);
```

Actually, it is much more common to have the building function return a pointer:

```
S* make_s(void) {
  S* p = malloc(sizeof(S));
  if (!p) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  // fill p
  return p;
}
```

Then call

```
S* ptr = make_s ();
```

The important thing is to document a convention about who should `free` the pointer. If the allocated structure contains internal pointer, make a routine `delete_s` which frees the internal pointer and the whole pointed structure.

BTW, avoid using `typedef` for pointers (like your `Sp`), you really want to know what is a pointer at a glance. Don't use `new` or `delete` in public C function names, because you may want later your header files to be included by C++ code.

Comment: @littlerunaway don't do this. you will cause heavy memory leak.

Comment: that's what I'm afraid of but I don't seem to have a choise since like I said, I can't change the function definition

Comment: @littlerunaway we have given you a solution.

Comment: `Sp*` is not a solution I can use

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo(Sp *p){
    *p = malloc.....
    *p->num = ....
}
```

then

```
Sp new = NULL;
foo(&new);
```

if you want to keep the prototype of the function as `void foo(Sp p)`, you have to go:

```
Sp new = (Sp) malloc(sizeof(S));
foo(new);
```

Comment: That works, but I think he said he can't change the function definition

Comment: can't do that since the argument will end up being S**, and that doesn't fir with the definition

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the function declaration, then you need to allocate the memory for the structure in `main`.

```
void foo(Sp ptr){
    ptr->num = ....
}
```

In main:

```
Sp itemPtr = malloc...;
foo( itemPtr );
```

Or this in main:

```
S item;
foo( &item );
```